# Acra alternative for comercial software

Tags: android, crash-reports

i'm programming an android app for my employer and I'm on the search for a crash reporter.

So far I found [Acra](https://code.google.com/p/acra/). Which really looks like what I'm searching for. However my employer doesn't like the Apache Licence.

Does anybody know of an alternative? Preferable a crash reporter sending crashes per email.

Thanks,
Xeno Lupus

Answer (score 0):

[HockeyApp](http://www.hockeyapp.net/crash-reports) is useful for crash reporting and beta-testing. Check out the site.